# Getting clicked innerhtml href

Tags: angular

I have a div with innerhtml containing multiple  link tags. When clicking on any of the a link tags I want to trigger a function in angular2. Can angular2 take over the click event of the href tags and get the clicked word or innerhtml tag which was clicked?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can add a host listener to your component and then figure out the rest from the passed event:

```
@HostListener('click', ['$event'])
onClick(event) {
  if(event.target ...) {

  }
}
```